# Augmented matrix rounding issue

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to create an augmented matrix to solve a problem, but I can't get to not round the values. The matrix `d` is trying to be augmented to the matrix `Diff`. I want the decimal values in `Diff` to remain decimals and the larger values in `d` to remain larger values, yet whenever I try to add it, MATLAB automatically reduces all of the values. Why is it doing this and how to fix it?

> > d = [74000;56000;10500;25000;17500;196000;5000]

```
d =

   74000
   56000
   10500
   25000
   17500
  196000
    5000
```

> > Diff = I - A

```
Diff =

 0.8412   -0.0064   -0.0025   -0.3404   -0.0014   -0.0083   -0.1594
-0.0057    0.7355   -0.0436   -0.0099   -0.0083   -0.0201   -0.3413
-0.0264   -0.1506    0.6443   -0.0139   -0.0142   -0.0070   -0.0236
-0.3299   -0.0565   -0.0495    0.6364   -0.0204   -0.0483   -0.0649
-0.0089   -0.0081   -0.0333   -0.0295    0.6588   -0.0237   -0.0020
-0.1190   -0.0901   -0.0996   -0.1260   -0.1722    0.7632   -0.3369
-0.0063   -0.0126   -0.0196   -0.0098   -0.0064   -0.0132    0.9988
```

> > Aug = [Diff,d]

```
Aug =

1.0e+05 *

 0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.7400
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.5600
-0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.1050
-0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.2500
-0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.1750
-0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    1.9600
-0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0500
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB is *not* rounding any values. If you look at the top left corner when you display `Aug`, you will see (`1.0e+05`) which means that all values being displayed are the actual values divided by `1e5` (fixed-decimal floating-point notation). Since you are concatenating very large values (`A`) with relatively small values (`Diff`), the significant digits of the small values don't appear because you are not displaying enough decimal points. As a result, they look like 0. This is an artifact of the way that your command window is displaying numbers.

You can [change the display format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html?refresh=true) to something else such as "shortg" which is typically used for large data ranges (the default is "short") and you will see that your data is not rounded.

```
format shortg

[Diff, d]

   0.8412      -0.0064      -0.0025      -0.3404      -0.0014      -0.0083      -0.1594        74000
  -0.0057       0.7355      -0.0436      -0.0099      -0.0083      -0.0201      -0.3413        56000
  -0.0264      -0.1506       0.6443      -0.0139      -0.0142       -0.007      -0.0236        10500
  -0.3299      -0.0565      -0.0495       0.6364      -0.0204      -0.0483      -0.0649        25000
  -0.0089      -0.0081      -0.0333      -0.0295       0.6588      -0.0237       -0.002        17500
   -0.119      -0.0901      -0.0996       -0.126      -0.1722       0.7632      -0.3369     1.96e+05
  -0.0063      -0.0126      -0.0196      -0.0098      -0.0064      -0.0132       0.9988         5000
```

In general, you should rarely rely on the MATLAB command window output for much. If you think your data is being rounded, then you would actually want to test this explicitly.

```
data = [Diff, d];
isequal(Diff, data(:,1:end-1))

    1
```